# The code ran successfully 1st time in console but when I refresh the page It gave me TypeError: Cannot read property 'summary' of undefined. Need hlp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

```
const Content = ()=>{
    const [news,setNews] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(()=> getNews(),[]);

    const getNews = async ()=>{
        const response = await fetch("https://apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com/news/list?category=generalnews&region=US", {
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "x-rapidapi-key": "---------------",
                "x-rapidapi-host": "apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
            }
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        setNews(data.items.result);
    }
    
    return(
        <div >
            {
                console.log(news[0].summary)
            }
            <News news={news}/>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Content;
```

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'summary' of undefined
this error is appearing for all the props**

Comment: Because on the first render `news` is empty. There is no first index. Add `if (!news.length) return <div />` before the return to catch the error.

Answer (score 1):

You should validate if news array contains any data. Check out below code

```
const Content = ()=>{
    const [news,setNews] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(()=> getNews(),[]);

    const getNews = async ()=>{
        const response = await fetch("https://apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com/news/list?category=generalnews&region=US", {
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "x-rapidapi-key": "---------------",
                "x-rapidapi-host": "apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
            }
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        setNews(data.items.result);
    }
    if(news && news.length> 0){
     
    return(
        <div >
            {
                console.log(news[0].summary)
            }
            <News news={news}/>
        </div>
    );
   }else{
     return <></>
   }
}
export default Content;
```

Comment: How should I render news component automatically when the data is available?

Comment: above code will re-render this component whenever state variable, i.e. `news` gets changed. So whenever your setter i.e. `setNews` gets called, your component will automatically rerender

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the problem as Andy suggested.
You can add another return statement like this to handle an empty array situation:

```
if (!news.length) return (<div>No news ATM!</div>)
return (
  <div>
    {console.log(news[0].summary)}
    <News news={news} />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: How should I render the news component automatically when the data is available?

Comment: useEffect will re-render automatically